# How to get a rotated linear gradient svg for use as a background image?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, canvas, data-uri

I've seen a few questions dancing around this, so I hope this isn't too redundant. Ideally, I'd like an `image/svg+xml` which scales to 100% of it's container. 
[Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla/gradient-editor) gets me a great start with a `data:image/svg+xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <linearGradient id="grad-ucgg-generated" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="0"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad-ucgg-generated)" />
</svg>
```

Note: the `width="100%" height="100%"` I'd like to take this gradient and rotate it by, say `65deg` 
The HTML5 canvas API provides a great way for me to build this image and then use `.toDataURL()` PNG to polyfill IE8 and IE7, but I'd like something scalable for IE9.

So the goal is to replicate this:

```
background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(239, 239, 214,0) 0%, rgba(239, 239, 214,.8) 100%),
linear-gradient(left,  rgba(239, 239, 214,0) 60%,rgba(207, 223, 144,1) 100%),
linear-gradient(right, rgba(239, 239, 214,0) 0%,rgba(239, 239, 214,1) 60%),
linear-gradient(top, rgba(239, 239, 214,0) 60%,#cfdf90 100%);
}
```

with an `image/svg+xml` that's 100% width and height.

I did try out http://svg-edit.googlecode.com but the interface was less than intuitive for the types of editing I wanted to do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To rotate the gradient you can e.g use the 'gradientTransform' attribute, like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" 
 viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <linearGradient id="grad-ucgg-generated" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
   x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientTransform="rotate(65)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="0"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad-ucgg-generated)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Please note that the `gradientTransform` attribute rotates the gradient according to it's anchor point at 0,0. To rotate it from the 'center' you need to calculate the proper percentages for x1, y1, x2 and y2. A simple PHP example:

```
// Rotation can be 0 to 360
$pi = $rotation * (pi() / 180);
$coords = array(
    'x1' => round(50 + sin($pi) * 50) . '%',
    'y1' => round(50 + cos($pi) * 50) . '%',
    'x2' => round(50 + sin($pi + pi()) * 50) . '%',
    'y2' => round(50 + cos($pi + pi()) * 50) . '%',
)
```

Comment: Easier to set the rotate origin in the gradientTransform surely as the two additional arguments to the rotate

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to set the rotate origin?

Comment: in gradientTransform="rotate(90, 50, 30)" the origin of the rotation would be 50, 30

Comment: @Robert actually in SVG it's different than CSS which is the format you have there with commas.  In the SVG spec it says transform paramaters are "(deg [x y])" separated by space, not comma.  So, your example might work with gradientTransform="rotate(90 50 30)", but if you wrote it in CSS with inline transform= it would indeed be with commas as you had it.  Tricky little difference had me stuck for a while on that one.  Reference:  https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

Comment: @OGSean Per https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute - scroll down to the BNF see this bit... "rotate" wsp* "(" wsp* number ( **comma**-wsp number **comma**-wsp number )? wsp* ")"

Comment: @RobertLongson with Chrome I seem to be able to get both ways to work, my mistake.

Comment: To rotate the gradient from its center (makes it easier to get the expected result) when `gradientUnits` is `userSpaceOnUse` (default), use `rotate(<angle> 0.5 0.5)`.

Comment: @cdoublev's comment needs to be seen! I spent hours trying to figure this out how to rotate around the centre before realising there was 'two more' comments.

Comment: This only works for square sized elements (width = height). How to do it on rectangles?

Answer (score 14):

Giel Berkers' solution in Javascript would be:

```
// angle can be 0 to 360
var anglePI = (angle) * (Math.PI / 180);
var angleCoords = {
    'x1': Math.round(50 + Math.sin(anglePI) * 50) + '%',
    'y1': Math.round(50 + Math.cos(anglePI) * 50) + '%',
    'x2': Math.round(50 + Math.sin(anglePI + Math.PI) * 50) + '%',
    'y2': Math.round(50 + Math.cos(anglePI + Math.PI) * 50) + '%',
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(65)">
```

Comment: This doesn't rotate on the center.