# How to fill the svg path based on percentage?

Tags: css, html, d3.js, svg, linear-gradients

[image]

I am using Linear gradient to indicate the percentage of the task completed. As u can see above its not calculated correctly. Currently I am just adding another path over an existing one.
Is there any way I can display the correct percentage? or Is there any other method to display the percentage.?

```
-
```

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/sashnk/pen/WLLJRo?editors=0010) to my code.

Comment: Instead of using `linearGradient` for this task I would use strokes: `stroke-dasharray`and  `stroke-dashoffset` for example like this: [Create a circle progressbar in svg or css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892517/create-a-circle-progressbar-in-svg-or-css/53893211#53893211)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031405/5385381

Comment: Please show me what you have. I would like to help.

Comment: Thanks. Please use this link for the code. https://codepen.io/sashnk/pen/ebPPwB

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in the question. Links can break. You seem to have had some of that in there in the past but you've removed it.

Comment: You can delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to recycle your `computeTextRotation` function to add `gradientTransform='rotate()'` with the computed angle.

```
grad.attr('gradientTransform' , function(d) {
  var angle = computeTextRotation(d);
  return `rotate(${angle + 90})`
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/PXxaRe)

Comment: Thanks.. I got the angles right but not able to show/calculate the percentage.
https://codepen.io/sashnk/pen/WLLJRo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I need to fill the Path with exact percentage. Pls see the link i jus mentioned.

Comment: Yes I have seen the link but it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hmm..for instance in my example arc "Sub A2" should be filled exactly 30%. But its filled above 60%. So how can I calculate the value of endAngle based on percentage?

Comment: What do you mean by `filled exactly 30%`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186648/discussion-between-ksav-and-devsa).